# Use terraform module output with other child module when output is tuple

Tags: module, terraform

I'm creating AWS S3 buckets with a module using a list of strings for the bucket names

Repo layout is like this

```
├── modules
│   └── s3
│       ├── main.tf
│       └── outputs.tf
├── main.tf
├── ouputs.tf
```

S3 module main.tf looks like this

```
variable "bucket_name" {
  type        = string
  description = "Bucket name"
  default     = ""
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket" "s3_bucket" {
  bucket = var.bucket_name
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "public" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id

  block_public_acls       = true
  block_public_policy     = true
  ignore_public_acls      = true
  restrict_public_buckets = true
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_acl" "acl" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id
  acl    = "private"
}

resource "aws_s3_bucket_versioning" "versioning" {
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id
  versioning_configuration {
    status = "Enabled"
  }
}
```

S3 module outputs.tf looks like this

```
# S3 bucket outputs
output "id" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.id
}

output "name" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.bucket
}

output "arn" {
  value = aws_s3_bucket.s3_bucket.arn
}
```

The parent main.tf looks like this

```
# Bucket list
locals {
  buckets = [
    "one",
    "two"
  ]
}

variable "random_string" {
  type        = string
  description = "(optional) describe your variable"
  default = "0i0iPKPK"
}

# Add data domain bucket
module "aws_s3_bucket" {
  source      = "./modules/s3"
  for_each    = toset(local.buckets)
  bucket_name = format("%s-%s", var.random_string, each.key)
}

# Add Snowflake storage integration(s)
module "snowflake_storage_integration" {
  providers = {
    snowflake = snowflake.github
  }
  source                           = "./modules/storageintegrations/"
  for_each                         = toset(local.buckets)
  bucket_storage_integration_name  = format("%s-%s", each.key, var.random_string)
  aws_s3_bucket_name               = ????
}
```

And the parent outputs.tf looks like this

```
# S3 bucket outputs
output "s3_bucket_id" {
  value = values(module.aws_s3_bucket)[*].id
}

output "s3_bucket_name" {
  value = values(module.aws_s3_bucket)[*].name
}

output "s3_bucket_arn" {
  value = values(module.aws_s3_bucket)[*].arn
}
```

I'm not entirely sure if I am doing this correctly?

The buckets are getting created with all the right names and settings, but am I outputting the S3 module outputs.tf correctly?

And, the next step will be to use each bucket with a snowflake storage integration

I cannot figure out how to get the S3 bucket name for each bucket and pass it to the integration module

I think right now my bucket names are tuples, but I think I need to get each value as a string?

Could anyone clarify if I have done this in a bad way?

Thanks

Comment: `module.aws_s3_bucket[each.key].name` should work where you put ???

Comment: Thanks for this, I tried that but it does not like it

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

on main.tf line 39, in module "snowflake_storage_integration":

39:   aws_s3_bucket_name               = [each.key].name

each.key is a string, known only after apply

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing doesn't seem *incorrect*, and if returning three separate tuples containing each of the different attribute values then that's a fine and valid thing to do.

Some people prefer to collect all of the results for a particular group of objects into a single output value that is a collection of objects though, since that can potentially make it easier to use that result outside of the module without having to first reassemble all of the correlated IDs, names, and ARNs. If that sounds valuable to you then you can achieve it using a single output value defined like the following:

```
output "s3_buckets" {
  value = {
    for n, b in module.aws_s3_bucket : n => {
      id   = b.id
      name = b.name
      arn  = b.arn
    }
  }
}
```

Neither of your approach and this other approach is universally *better*; it really just depends on how you'll be using these results. If you won't yet be using these output values for anything other than human reference anyway then there's certainly no harm in sticking with what you have and waiting until you have a stronger reason to prefer a particular shape of outputs, and can therefore make a more reasoned design tradeoff based on your learned requirements.

Comment: I'm trying to pass the output of each bucketname from the s3 module to the snowflake_storage_integration module